# Load an Extension (.dll) in UWP with Full Trust?

Tags: windows-runtime, uwp, winrt-component

It is possible to load a whole process in Full Trust mode in a WinRT application adding this to its AppManifest:

```
<desktop:Extension Category="windows.fullTrustProcess" Executable="Win32Process_CPP.exe" />
```

While it works and I could potentially create a Service out of that, I would like to know if it is also possible to load a DLL in the same Full Trust manner.

e.g.,

```
<Extension Category="[something]">
  <InProcessServer>
    <Path>[MyWin32orCLR.dll]</Path>
    <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="[Something]" ThreadingModel="both" />
  </InProcessServer>
</Extension>
```

So I can call a function on MyWin32orCLR.dll with full trust access.

I know anything like this won't be publishable for the Windows Store but that is fine; I am trying to create a in-house App.

Comment: This is basically registration for the your component and it tells Windows that the object `Something` can be found in `MyWin32orCLR.dll`. According to the behavior of this expansion to decide whether to have full trust.

Comment: Thanks, @NicoZhu-MSFT , that being the case, I don't think the object or library will have Full Trust by default. Is there a way I can let it have so?